Возвращение панели из главного меню: telebot Python
У меня есть тг бот, я все еще с ним борюсь, ахахаха
Суть вопроса такая: у меня есть основная часть бота - главное меню, которое имеет панель быстрых команд:

После перехода на "Как пользоваться приложениями", пользователю выдается другая панель

В данном окне клиент должен выбрать соответствующее видео. Все работает, видео отправляется, только проблема заключается в том, что после выбора должно открываться меню главного окна, но я не знаю, как вызвать его из иного файла. Только новое создавать? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Сам Код основного файла:
if (message.text == "Как пользоваться приложениями"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        itembtn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Poizon")
        itembtn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("TaoBao")
        itembtn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
        markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2)
        markup.add(itembtn3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите нужное приложение или вернитесь в главное меню", reply_markup = markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, Video.choice_app)

Второй файл
def choice_app(message):
    if(message.text == "Poizon"):
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open("video/Poizon.mp4", "rb"), supports_streaming = True)

    elif(message.text == "TaoBao"):
       bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open("video/TaoBao.mp4", "rb"), supports_streaming = True)
    else:
        message.text = "Exit"
        return(message)


Для адекватной работы с меню рекомендую использовать aiogram_dialog, соответственно, используя aiogram. Только там вы сможете нормально создавать меню. Ну и если вы делаете бота многопользовательским, то вам 100% придётся сменить библиотеку на aiogram.

Не знаю, что вы имеете ввиду под "многопользовательским", извините. Он по сути работает только с тем пользователем, который к нему обращается, ну как чат. А вообще, если код находится в 1 файле, все работает нормально, а вот если разделять на файлы, то тут я уже начинаю задумываться о логике программы, ахах

Почитайте про асинхронность, если бот будет обрабатывать несколько запросов синхронно, то это очень замедлит его скорость работы. Помещайте код в функции, а затем импортируйте это функции туда, где это необходимо.

@АртёмКовалев подскажите, после выбора чего конкретно должно открывать меню главного окна? Т.е. после получения файла - должно сразу открываться главное окно ("главное меню" наверное так правильнее). Или после нажатия на кнопку "Вернуться в главное меню" - user возвращается в главное меню - верно?

@Kavermoki, правильно. По сути при нажатии на кнопку "вернуться в главное меню" пользователь открывает главное окно по новой, а вот при нажатии на иную кнопку сначала должно отправиться видео, а уже потом открыться главное меню (главная панель). В основной программе все работает по правильной логике, а вот в дробленных файлах информация не доходит

@BenPuls, хорошо, спасибо, обязательно почитаю !

Не знаю, правильно ли я поступил, но я вынес markup в отдельный файл и просто импортировал его в программу, и когда бот отправляет видео, он автоматически меняет панель на главное меню. Крч оно работает, не знаю только, правильно или нет, но меня все устраивает

Я просто вынес панель (markup) в отдельный файл и просто импортировал его в основной файл как модуль, из-за чего после отправки видео или ссылки на приложение панель автоматически меняется на основную.
Оно работает! И даже немного быстрее, чем раньше, но может это немного неправильно?
